# How to update the state of Cell from List depending of the value inside an array React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array, each of the item inside the Array will render a component like this:

```
const MyList ({ detailsArray }) => {

   return(
     {detailsArray.length > 0 && detailsArray.map((item, key) =>
        <DetailCell
            key={key}
            customerDetail={item}
            index={key}
            errorObject={detailsWithError} 

       />
      )}
   )
}
```

**What I want to do is,** when I click on a button in `MyList`, I will need to check the each item in `detailsArray`. If the item having error, I will update the border of that particular `DetailCell` to red color.

**This is what I tried:**

In `MyList` , I have a button, when click will check all the `item` inside `detailsArray` see whether is ok or not:

```
<Button
     onClick={() => processButtonOnClick()}
>
     MyButton
</Button>

function processButtonOnClick(){
    if (detailsArray.forEach(checkDetailsBeforeSent)) {
          // if everything ok, do other stuff
    }else{
        // do other stuff 
    }
}

function checkDetailsBeforeSent(item, index) {
   // here is the function check each item, see whether the details ok or not 
   // for example, if name or phone number is blank, I want to update the cell border to red 
   
   if(item.name === ""){
      // here need to update the cell 
   }

   if(item.phone_number === ""){
      // here need to update the cell 
   }

}
```

So in order for me to update the cell that having problem, I tried to create a hook inside `MyList` and then pass it do into `DetailCell`

```
// create a hook in MyList
const [detailsWithError, setDetailsWithError] = useState([])

// create a blank errorObject, cause I need to pass an errorMessage as well 
const errorObject = {
   index: '',
   errorMessage: ''
}

// then I update the hook, when the item is having error (Inside checkItemBeforeSent function) like this: 
if (item.name === "") {
    errorObject.errorMessage = "Name cannot empty"
    errorObject.index = index
    setDetailsWithError(detailsWithError.push(errorObject))
    return false
 }
```

So now the item that having error, I push it inside a hook, with the `index` of the `item` and also its error message.

Now I want to update this error message into the `DetailCell` , so the `DetailCell` that having error, its border will be `red` color, and display the `errorMessage` as well.

But I don't know how to do that.

**I tried:**

```
in MyList 

{customerDetailsList.length > 0 && customerDetailsList.map((item, key) =>
   <DetailCell
       key={key}
       customerDetail={item}
       index={key}
       />
       ? 
       !check(key) // here I have a logic, if the detailsWithError array have error, render text,else as usual
       :
     <Text>This have error</Text>

)}

// the check function , to check whether the array contain the key as index 
const check = (key) => {
    detailsWithError.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (item.index === key) {
          return true
     } else {
       return false
    }
  })
}
```

But end up, it didnt render any `DetailCell` from the above function.

**What I want:**

1. Click a button, check all the item inside `detailsArray`, if a item having error, update that particular `DetailCell` border to red.

Thanks in advance.

**Here is the CodeSandbox** [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-glade-r8l1u?file=/src/components/subsribe-form.js)

My code is inside `component/my-list.js` and `component/detail-cell.js`

Comment: Could you post a sandbox for the same ?

Comment: ok sure. wait a minute..

Comment: hey sir, https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-glade-r8l1u?file=/src/components/my-list.js 
My code is inside `my-list.js` and `detail-cell.js`

Comment: [Array push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
```detailsWithError.push(errorObject)``` return new length of your list. so ```setDetailsWithError(detailsWithError.push(errorObject))``` does not make scene

Comment: @HiepLe so what should I do? Besides that, still have any problem in my code? Or if it for you, how will you solve this problem?

Comment: ```borderColor={"gray.200" ? errorObjectArray.index !== index : "red"}``` ??? ```"gray.200" ?``` is always true. I can not understand your code and logic, why don't you check error when render like ```borderColor={checkError(item) ? "gray.200" : "red"}```